# Finding the fixed points of a complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find the fix point of the mapping $w=z^2 +(1+i)z-1$. I know if I graph this complex function then graph the line $y=x$ the points where both functions overlap will be the fix points, but how do find these points using algebra methods. any idea.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: a fixed point of function $f$ is a solution of the equation $f(z) = z$.
You do know how to solve quadratic equations?

Comment: yeah I solve the quadratic equation but I am not convince that the z values that I find are the fixed point because when I plug them back to the original function I did not get the same value of what z equal at. by definition that I have in my notes state that $f(z_{0}) = z_{0}) $

Comment: If so, you  made a mistake in the solution.  What did you get?